# Как массово изменить часть имени файлов?

Tags: php

На сервере есть папка с подпапками, в которых лежат изображения разных форматов . Подскажите, как можно массово изменить в именах этих файлов одну часть на другую?

Примеры названия файла - 12312312_name_file.png, 1f34f4r_name_file.jpg

соответственно name_file нужно заменить на другое название.

Comment: С сем конкретно проблема - с переименованием или с заменой строки в названии или с тем, что файлов много?

Comment: Больше с вложенностью. Как перебрать все файлы и сохранить иерархию.

Comment: Рекурсивно проходить все файлы в папке, с помощью is_dir проверять, папка ли, добавлять имя к пути и заходить внутрь. И так далее.